# Disabling ProxyCreationEnabled breaks JsonConvert.SerializeObject and quits VS debugging

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net

I'm trying to serialize to json some data from EF6 DB first entities.

The first problem was that I was doing lazy loading, and closed the data context, then I got `Context Disposed` error when doing `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataFromEntities)`.

So I set `context.Configuraton.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` so all propreties that are not included are `null` by default. The problem now is that when i try to serialize, Visual Studio 2019 just quit debuggin and don't give any exception message. I have my code in a try-catch but it don't catch anything.

What I'm doing wrong?

I also tried to disable lazy loading but the result is the same. Here is the code:

```
using (var oContext = new DBContext.UDCSDesign())
{
   oContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; //If i remove this line I get Object Disposed error on serialization

   var oFieldDictionaryList = oContext.FieldDictionary
                          .Include(oField => oField.DropdownItem)
                          .ToList();
}
```

And then:

```
try{
    string sDocJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oFieldDictionaryList, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
                    });
}
catch (Exception ex){
}
```

Comment: You might need to put the complete method structure rather than fragments. You've declared a string inside a `try` block and done nothing else within that scope. What do you expect this method to do? Are you setting breakpoints that aren't getting hit?

Comment: @StevePy I just pasted the relevant code. The error occurs on `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`. I expect to convert a list of objects from db to json string.

Comment: That's the problem... what you think is relevant code may not be the source of your issue. What I see is two separate blocks that would not even compile. You have a using block scoping retrieval of data, then a separate try/catch block referencing that loaded collection. With lazy loading on, a context disposed error would indicate the serialization is happening outside of the scope of the DbContext.  Normally disabling the proxy would simply cause it to deal with the nulls for anything not eager loaded, but if that's not the case, something else in your specific implementation is in play.